# ConcurrentModificationException in a loop

Tags: java, android, collections, iteration, concurrentmodification

I'm running this code on a separate Thread (not the UI Thread)

```
strains = new ArrayList<Strain>();
for (Breeder b : breeders) {
   for (Strain s : b.getStrains()) {
        strains.add(s);
    }
}
```

It sometime causes ConcurrentModificationException. 
I know that i can't add or remove object from a Collection that i'm iterating, but in this snippet I'm not iterating on strains. Where i'm wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Synchronize**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) your access. This kind of *freezes* the current `breeder` object, so that it will not be modified in any other thread. Methods that try to do this will be blocked. Blocked means that they just *wait* (like System.sleep(x)), until the `synchronized` block in the other thread has been processed.

```
synchronized(breeders) {
    for (Breeder b : breeders) {
       for (Strain s : b.getStrains()) {
            strains.add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure that you also put `synchronized` around the other threads' access to `breeders`.

Comment: That could be the issue. Or it could be the loop over the breeder strains. But synchronizing the access won't change anything unless all the threads do the same thing every time they access the collection. It should be encapsulated inside a class.

Comment: I tried synchronizing the breedes acces, but no help.. The exception is fired here "for (Breeder b : breeders)"